# Can't get the chapter numbers displayed in the customized Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, counters, titletoc

I'm trying to get the chapter number displayed in the TOC. Here's my current code:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\definecolor{tbl}{HTML}{F035A3}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\makeatletter
\titlecontents{chapter}[3.7pc]
{%
  \addvspace{30pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \draw[fill=tbl,draw=tbl] (-7,-.1) rectangle (-0.7,.5);%
    \pgftext[left,x=-3.6cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Lecture\ \thecontentslabel};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \color{tbl}\large\sc\bfseries%
}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=tbl,draw=tbl] (2pt,0) rectangle (4,0.1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{2pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
{}
{}
{\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
[ \textbullet\ ][]
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \chapter*{%
    \vspace*{-20\p@}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
      \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{tbl}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
      \draw[fill=tbl,draw=tbl] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
      \clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
      \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\lecture[2]{%
  \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
  \section*{Lecture #1: #2}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \lecture{5}{Hi}
  \lecture{1}{Hi}
  \lecture{9}{Hi}
  \lecture{10}{Hi}
  \lecture{2}{Hi}
\end{document}
```

which creates the following PDF:

[image]

How can I get the chapter number displayed on the left-hand side next to the **Lecture** text? I've tried adding `\arabic{chapter}`, `\thechapter`. I've even tried creating a counter and a variable and putting that in front of the **Lecture** text, but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer (via chatgpt). I just had to change the line from:

```latex
\pgftext[left,x=-3.6cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Lecture\ \thecontentslabel};%
```

to

```latex
\pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Lecture~\thecontentslabel\\*\hspace*{.7em}\ \thecontentslabel};
```